# Can OPA be used in use-cases where the concurrency and throughput is very high?

Tags: opa, open-policy-agent

I'm running OPA as a server(running on AWS) and I did couple of performance test,

1. For the first test I allocated 1 vCPU for the OPA container but for a concurrency of 100 I got a throughput of 2.5k requests per second.
2. I increased the resource allocation to 4 vCPU, but even with sufficient resource I'm not able achieve better throughput.

Am I missing anything here or do we have any configuration I must pass to the OPA container to make to effective against high load(say 2000 concurrency and and 40K rps)?

Thank you